# Missing Data Extension in Journey Builder Contacts Configuration

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

When opening the Contacts Configuration section in Contact Builder, is there a reason why there are no Data Extensions appearing? The only option show an Email Addresses folder with Email Address sub option. When choosing to "Add Address" shouldn't a list of Data Extensions become available?

Answer (score 0):

The Data Extension must first be marked as a Population within Data Designer (or legacy Data Extensions marked 'Use as Root' in Data Designer) before it can be added to the Channel Address Order.